# How to know if a message has been ack-ed / nack-ed?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I'm trying to know when a message has been accepted (ack) or not (nack) using RabbitMQ and Spring Boot.

I want to send a message into a queue (via exchange) and check if the queue has been accepted the message. Actually I want to send to two different queues, but it is not important, I'm assuming if it works for one of them will work for the other too.

So I've tried something like this using `CorrelationData`:

```java
public boolean sendMessage(...) {
    CorrelationData cd = new CorrelationData();
    this.rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange, routingKey, message, cd);
    try {
        return cd.getFuture().get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS).isAck();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

The line `cd.getFuture().get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS).isAck()` should get `false` is value has not been `ack` into the queue I think. But this is always true, even if `routingKey` doesn't exists.
So I'm assuming this piece of code is checking the message has been send into the `exchange` and `exchange` says "yes, I've recived the message, it has not been routed, but I've recived it".

So, I've looked for other ways into Rabbit/Spring documentation but I can't get the way.

And, explaining a little more, that I want is:

Into Spring Boot code I receive a message. This message has to been send to other queues/exchange, but can't be removed from the current queue (i.e. *acked*) until other two queues confirm the `ack`.

I have manual ack and as a little pseudo-code I have this:

```java
@RabbitListener(queues = {queue})
public void receiveMessageFromDirect(Message message, Channel channel,
                                     @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag){
    boolean sendQueue1 = sendMessage(...);
    boolean sendQueue2 = sendMessage(...);

    if(sendQueue1 && sendQueue2){
        //both messages has been readed; now I can ack this message
        channel.basicAck(tag, false);
    }else{ 
        //nacked; I can't remove the message util both queue ack the message
        channel.basicNack(tag,false,true);
    }
```

I've tested this structure and, even if the queues don't exists, values `sendQueue1` and `sendQueue2` are always true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confirm is true; even for unroutable messages (I am not entirely sure why).

You need to enable returned messages (and check that it is null in the `CorrelationData` after the future completes - `correlationData.getReturnedMessage()`). If it's not null, the message wasn't routable to any queue.

You only get nacks if there is a bug in the broker, or if you are using a queue with `x-max-length` and overflow behavior `reject-publish`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. So, even if I mannually do a `nack`, the line `getFuture()...isAck()` will be true?

Comment: There is no connection between the producer and consumer; they are completely decoupled; the ack on the producer side is simply whether the message was received by the broker; on the consumer side, the ack/nack is whether the consumer successfully received the message; there is no communication back to the producer. Messaging systems are decoupled like this by design. The third parameter on the consumer side tells the broker whether to requeue (and redeliver) the message or discard it (or route it to a DLQ, if so configured).